# C# freeze process while using Show instead of ShowDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing an addin for an specific program (Autodesk Revit).
Within this addin, i am showing a WinForm to the user.
With a button on the winform, the user will be temporary sent back to the main application (Autodesk Revit) to make a selection, and once finished it will be sent back to the WinForm.

When initializing the Winform, i can either use the `Form.Show()` or use `Form.ShowDialog()`

If i would be using the `Form.Show()` The form will proper display and a button on the form can be used to let the user make a selection in the main application and send him back to the form when he is done with his selection using `this.hide()`before the selection and `this.Show()` after to make the form temporarily hidden during selection process.

If i would be using the `Form.ShowDialog()` The form will proper display and a button on the form can be used, but because the ShowDialog freezes the main application while waiting for the dialogresults, the user wont be able to make a selection.

So thats why i would want to go with the `Form.Show()` instead of `Form.ShowDialog()`.

But here is the issue i am facing:
If i use the `Form.Show()`, the form can be moved to the background or another monitor, and because the main application is not in a frozen state, the user can just continue working and completely forget the form is still open.

So i am wondering if it is possible to somehow idle/freeze the main application as if i was using the `ShowDialog` while in reality using the `Show` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to adjust your logic a bit:

- use `ShowDialog`, but close the form to return to the original application
- devise a method of saving the forms state (e.g. serialize to a `MemoryStream`) before closing.
- recreate the form and restore its state before showing it modal again when you want the user to be sent to the form again.

Comment: yea this was in fact a workaround i was thinking of. Just call the close when i invoke the selection command, and once the user selection is done, i start a new instance of the form and retrieve the current selection state of the application. In that case i would be able to use the ShowDialog(), although it feels more as an workaround then a solid solution

Comment: I don't think of it as a workaround, more as the architectural concept of your application (analoguous to e.g. the client - server nature of a web app)

Comment: As this isn't really a code answer, I'll post it here as a comment.  An alternative would be to use a program (like ILSpy) to view the disassembled Form.ShowDialog code and emulate that behaviour yourself in your Form, modified for your specific scenario. -- That said, I believe @JohanDonne's suggestion will be easier to implement.

Comment: @SamAxe no need to use IL Spy, Microsoft publishes [the source code for that function](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs.html#0bb4691914851ddb)

Answer (score 0):

Using another thread won't hang your main form when using `ShowDialogue()` Use the code below:

```
        //Initially
        this.Enabled = false;
        Form form = new YourForm();
        form.TopMost = true;
        form.Focus();
        System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => form.ShowDialog());
        thread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest; //<- just an example, set it according to your need
        thread.Start();



        //If you want to close it from the main form (you can do it from the opened form itself though)
        form.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            form.Close();
        });
        thread.Abort();
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.Enabled = true;
        this.Focus();
        this.TopMost = false;
```

Comment: Even in that case, the user could just minimize or close the Winform and continue working in the original application.

Comment: Do you want the other form to be unclosable?

Comment: The main application is basically the Host, and my form cant exist if the main application would be closed. So i only want to freeze the main (as would happen when using showdialog) while really using .show and freeze it by code

Comment: That is why I added (this.Enabled = false;) it will render your host disabled until you enable it through the code